# Get photos by hashtag from instagram API after June 1, 2016

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get all photos by a specified hashtag from instagram API, not just the photos on my account. Since the changes of June 1, 2016 it doesn't work anymore. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So, my code did that, I could get all photos based on a specified hashtag, however after the changes in June 1 I can't anymore. I only can get photos on my account now. So that's the question, how can I get all photos from any users with the certain hashtag after these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After June 1st 2016, you have to get your app reviewed and approved by instagram to get API access, if not you will be in Sandbox mode which will have access only to your account.

You also have to add `public_content` to scope during authentication and get approved by instagram to access hashtags from API.